# Problems to animate md-button when it is resize

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-animate

I would like to animate a md-button when I add a md-progress-circular inside it.

```
<div class="layout-row layout-align-center-center" ng-init="label = true">
        <ng-button class="btn btn-default-rb center-block rb-margin-top-a" 
                    ng-click="label = !label"
                    layout="row"
                    style="background-color: #FF8800;">
            ng-button &nbsp;
            <md-progress-circular ng-if="!label" 
                md-mode="indeterminate" 
                class="md-hue-2 rb-margin-left-a"
                md-diameter="20px"></md-progress-circular>
        </ng-button>
    </div>
```

You can see the example here:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/LkAQ92OztNgbEjztHvCS?p=preview
```

My idea is to show this progress when I post some data. The progress bar is showed, but I would like to show an animation while the button is resized, like the ladda expand right (http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/).

Could you help me?